# Ember js set value in TextField from URL params

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using this bin as an exmaple: http://jsbin.com/acUm/31/edit

I want users to be able to visit the URL of a filter search and have the params in the URL populate the TextField. I currently have it working so that a user can visit the URL directly, but the TextField is empty. That is not an ideal user experience.

How can I get two way binding on the value of that field?

Comment: I am currently trying this approach in the view: 
Alivecor.FilterPatientsView = Ember.TextField.extend

  didInsertElement: ->
    lastName = params
    this.$().val()
Now I just need to figure out how to get the params to this hook....

Comment: OK, I solved it by setting @.controllerFor('thecontroller').set('lastName', params.last_name)

Comment: Hi Jason, I encoutering the exact same issue and couldn't quite figure out your solution. Can you expain (or update the jsbin with a working example) - Thanks!